# react react-bootstrap button cannot set custom height. only can set width with css

Tags: html, css, react-bootstrap

I have been stuck on this issue and have not found a way to adjust the height of react-bootstrap button with css styling. I am able to set the width. Here is my following code

JSX

Inside the Render and return code

```
<div className="row">
  <Button className="btn-danger btn-edit btn btn-default">Button 1</Button>
<Button className="btn-danger btn-edit btn btn-default">Button 2</Button>
<Button className="btn-info btn-edit btn btn-default">Button 3</Button>
<Button className="btn-success btn-edit btn btn-default">Button 4</Button>
<Button className="btn-primary btn-edit btn btn-default">Button 5</Button>
</div>

in my style code, I added a class for each to add custom height and weight

.btn-danger {
  width: 25% !important
  height: 20% !important
}
.btn-success {
  width: 25% !important
  height: 20% !important
}
.btn-primary {
  width: 25% !important
  height: 20% !important
}
.btn-info {
  width: 25% !important
  height: 20% !important
}
.btn-success {
  width: 25% !important
  height: 20% !important
}
```

I hit F12 to inspect the button and add/adjust height for btn, btn-danger etc... the height does not change at all.

at trying these steps, I am out of ideas on what to try next. I would think that if the custom class allows me to change the width, it would also let me change the height.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Some other things to look for that may be causing issues: sometimes there are other parent classes or `ID` classes that may be used in the application that are overwriting your class. Also look for inline styles or Javascript that gets called that that may have CSS that could also overwrite your styling.

Answer (score 1):

found the solution. Changed height to min-height in the css.